# javascript array updating using common key

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 javascript arrays with below content:

Array1:

```
[{"key":"Agents"},{"key":"Formal"},{"key":"Annotation"},{"key":"Business"}]
```

Array2:

```
[
    {"key":"Agents","class":"newclass","text":"Agents"}, 
    {"key":"Business","class":"newclass1","text":"Business"},
    {"key":"Formal","class":"newclass2","text":"Formal"},
    {"key":"Annotation","class":"class5","text":"Annotation"},
    {"key":"Rate","class":"newclass1","text":"Rates"}
]
```

The keys in both arrays are same. I am looking to update the **array1** with the `class` and `text values` from **array2** by matching keys.
Is there a way to do it without iterating both the arrays? This is just a small subset of the array. the actual can be a little larger.

Comment: You should show what you've tried, but also, why wouldn't you just copy the array? Are there duplicates in the second array?

Comment: "Is there a way to do it without iterating both the arrays?" no

Comment: I was trying iterating both arrays but not very good at javascript so just wanted to clarify/confirm if there is any other way. Also cannot copy arrays because the second one could have more items which I dont want to add.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you would need to iterate through both arrays in order to find the right object in each array. Even using built in js prototype methods you would be iterating through the array.

One way you could solve this is my modifying your data structure. Instead of using an array of dictionaries, make a dictionary of dictionaries like so:

First Array:

```
{
    "Agents": {},
    "Business": {},
    "Formal": {},
    "Annotation": {},
    "Rate": {}
}
```

Second Array:

```
{
    "Agents": {
        "class": "newclass",
        "text": "Agents"
    },
    "Business": {
        "class": "newclass1",
        "text": "Business"
    },
    "Formal": {
        "class": "newclass2",
        "text": "Formal"
    },
    "Annotation": {
        "class": "newclass5",
        "text": "Annotation"
    },
    "Rate": {
        "class": "newclass1",
        "text": "Rates"
    }
}
```

Now you can do something like `Array1["Agents"] = Array2["Agents"]` or however you want to add the data.

Comment: thanks its a good suggestion will have to see if I can modify the existing arrays to produce this kind of structure.

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the properties across if you require new objects but it looks like array one is just a filter set of array two - you could simply map the first to every corresponding second.  Iterating through both arrays can't be avoided but you can always create a map / ID cache so that you only make a single pass over each.

```js
const arr1 = [
    {"key": "Agents"},
    {"key": "Formal"},
    {"key": "Annotation"},
    {"key": "Business"}
]

const arr2 = [
    {"key": "Agents", "class": "newclass", "text": "Agents"}, 
    {"key": "Business", "class": "newclass1", "text": "Business"},
    {"key": "Formal", "class": "newclass2", "text": "Formal"},
    {"key": "Annotation", "class": "class5", "text": "Annotation"},
    {"key": "Rate", "class": "newclass1", "text": "Rates"}
]

const transformer = from => {
    const cache = from.reduce((map, item) => (
        map[item.key] = item, map
    ), {})
    return ({ key }) => cache[key]
}

console.log(
    arr1.map(transformer(arr2))
)
```